# Algorithms for moving the cursor to a date on a 12 month rotating calendar in Emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

**GOAL**:  The goal of this thread is to create two (2) mathematical formulas to replace the long-hand solution by @lawlist in the function `lawlist-calendar-cursor-to-visible-date` (below).

**STORY PROBLEM**

There now exists a 12-month calendar in Emacs that scrolls forwards and backwards one month (or more) at a time.  The function `lawlist-calendar-cursor-to-visible-date` is used to mark dates with overlays for designated events (e.g., birthdays, holidays, appointments, etc.); or, to simply move the cursor to a particular date.  @lawlist has devised a solution by long-hand, which does not entirely use mathematical equations to calculate the cursor position for each of the 365 days that are displayed.  It may be possible to create two (2) concise algorithms to replace the long-hand solution.

A working draft of the 12-month scrolling calendar (*without* the long-hand solution) may be found here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21409154/2112489

**LEGEND**:

`displayed-month` (numbers 1 through 12) is the month that appears in the upper left-hand corner of the buffer, and this changes as the 12-month calendar is scrolled forwards or backwards.

The target `month` (numbers 1 through 12) is the month that we need to locate with assistance from the two mathematical formulas -- its location varies depending upon the date being marked (e.g., birthday, holiday, appointment), and depending upon the `displayed-month` in the upper left-hand corner of the buffer.  The target `month` can be in any one of 12 possible positions.  There are three (3) possible `x` axis coordinates (i.e., **6**, **31**, or **56**).  There are four (4) possible `y` axis coordinates (i.e., **0**, **9**, **18** or **27**).  [Citation to x / y coordinates:  http://www.mathsisfun.com/data/cartesian-coordinates.html ]

A `row` is defined as 3 months horizontally.

A `column` is defined as 4 months vertically.

The first forumula must equal **0**, **9**, **18** or **27** depending upon whether the point is on `row` 1, 2, 3 or 4 -- i.e., from top to bottom.

The second forumula must equal **6**, **31**, or **56** depending upon whether the point is on `column` 1, 2 or 3 -- i.e., from left to right.

**EXAMPLE**:

- If `displayed-month` is January (i.e., 1) and the target `month` is August (i.e., 8), then `row` equals **18** and `column` equals **31**.
- If `displayed-month` is February (i.e., 2) and the target `month` is August (i.e., 8), then `row` equals **18** and `column` equals **6**.
- If `displayed-month` is March (i.e., 3) and the target `month` is August (i.e., 8), then `row` equals **9** and `column` equals **56**.
- If `displayed-month` is April (i.e., 4) and target `month` is August (i.e., 8), then `row` equals **9** and `column` equals **31**.
- If `displayed-month` is May (i.e., 5) and the target `month` is August (i.e., 8), then `row` equals **9** and `column` equals **6**.

The 12-month calendar looks like the following as the layout scrolls forward one month at a time:

```
;;  1 2 3
;;  4 5 6
;;  7 8 9
;;  10 11 12

;;  2 3 4
;;  5 6 7
;;  8 9 10
;;  11 12 1

;;  3 4 5
;;  6 7 8
;;  9 10 11
;;  12 1 2

;;  4 5 6
;;  7 8 9
;;  10 11 12
;;  1 2 3

;;  5 6 7
;;  8 9 10
;;  11 12 1
;;  2 3 4

;;  6 7 8
;;  9 10 11
;;  12 1 2
;;  3 4 5

;;  7 8 9
;;  10 11 12
;;  1 2 3
;;  4 5 6

;;  8 9 10
;;  11 12 1
;;  2 3 4
;;  5 6 7

;;  9 10 11
;;  12 1 2
;;  3 4 5
;;  6 7 8

;;  10 11 12
;;  1 2 3
;;  4 5 6
;;  7 8 9

;;  11 12 1
;;  2 3 4
;;  5 6 7
;;  8 9 10

;;  12 1 2
;;  3 4 5
;;  6 7 8
;;  9 10 11
```

The long-hand solution by @lawlist is as follows:

```
(defun lawlist-calendar-cursor-to-visible-date (date)
  "Move the cursor to DATE that is on the screen."
  (let* (
      (month (calendar-extract-month date))
      (day (calendar-extract-day date))
      (year (calendar-extract-year date))
      (first-of-month-weekday (calendar-day-of-week (list month 1 year))))
    (goto-line
      (+ 3
        ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
        (cond
          ;;  1 2 3
          ;;  4 5 6
          ;;  7 8 9
          ;;  10 11 12
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 1)
              (memq month `(1 2 3)))
            0)
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 1)
              (memq month `(4 5 6)))
            9)
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 1)
              (memq month `(7 8 9)))
            18)
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 1)
              (memq month `(10 11 12)))
            27)
          ;;  2 3 4
          ;;  5 6 7
          ;;  8 9 10
          ;;  11 12 1
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 2)
              (memq month `(2 3 4)))
            0)
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 2)
              (memq month `(5 6 7)))
            9)
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 2)
              (memq month `(8 9 10)))
            18)
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 2)
              (memq month `(11 12 1)))
            27)
          ;;  3 4 5
          ;;  6 7 8
          ;;  9 10 11
          ;;  12 1 2
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 3)
              (memq month `(3 4 5)))
            0)
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 3)
              (memq month `(6 7 8)))
            9)
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 3)
              (memq month `(9 10 11)))
            18)
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 3)
              (memq month `(12 1 2)))
            27)
          ;;  4 5 6
          ;;  7 8 9
          ;;  10 11 12
          ;;  1 2 3
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 4)
              (memq month `(4 5 6)))
            0)
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 4)
              (memq month `(7 8 9)))
            9)
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 4)
              (memq month `(10 11 12)))
            18)
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 4)
              (memq month `(1 2 3)))
            27)
          ;;  5 6 7
          ;;  8 9 10
          ;;  11 12 1
          ;;  2 3 4
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 5)
              (memq month `(5 6 7)))
            0)
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 5)
              (memq month `(8 9 10)))
            9)
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 5)
              (memq month `(11 12 1)))
            18)
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 5)
              (memq month `(2 3 4)))
            27)
          ;;  6 7 8
          ;;  9 10 11
          ;;  12 1 2
          ;;  3 4 5
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 6)
              (memq month `(6 7 8)))
            0)
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 6)
              (memq month `(9 10 11)))
            9)
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 6)
              (memq month `(12 1 2)))
            18)
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 6)
              (memq month `(3 4 5)))
            27)
          ;;  7 8 9
          ;;  10 11 12
          ;;  1 2 3
          ;;  4 5 6
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 7)
              (memq month `(7 8 9)))
            0)
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 7)
              (memq month `(10 11 12)))
            9)
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 7)
              (memq month `(1 2 3)))
            18)
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 7)
              (memq month `(4 5 6)))
            27)
          ;;  8 9 10
          ;;  11 12 1
          ;;  2 3 4
          ;;  5 6 7
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 8)
              (memq month `(8 9 10)))
            0)
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 8)
              (memq month `(11 12 1)))
            9)
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 8)
              (memq month `(2 3 4)))
            18)
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 8)
              (memq month `(5 6 7)))
            27)
          ;;  9 10 11
          ;;  12 1 2
          ;;  3 4 5
          ;;  6 7 8
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 9)
              (memq month `(9 10 11)))
            0)
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 9)
              (memq month `(12 1 2)))
            9)
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 9)
              (memq month `(3 4 5)))
            18)
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 9)
              (memq month `(6 7 8)))
            27)
          ;;  10 11 12
          ;;  1 2 3
          ;;  4 5 6
          ;;  7 8 9
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 10)
              (memq month `(10 11 12)))
            0)
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 10)
              (memq month `(1 2 3)))
            9)
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 10)
              (memq month `(4 5 6)))
            18)
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 10)
              (memq month `(7 8 9)))
            27)
          ;;  11 12 1
          ;;  2 3 4
          ;;  5 6 7
          ;;  8 9 10
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 11)
              (memq month `(11 12 1)))
            0)
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 11)
              (memq month `(2 3 4)))
            9)
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 11)
              (memq month `(5 6 7)))
            18)
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 11)
              (memq month `(8 9 10)))
            27)
          ;;  12 1 2
          ;;  3 4 5
          ;;  6 7 8
          ;;  9 10 11
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 12)
              (memq month `(12 1 2)))
            0)
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 12)
              (memq month `(3 4 5)))
            9)
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 12)
              (memq month `(6 7 8)))
            18)
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 12)
              (memq month `(9 10 11)))
            27) )
        ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
          (/ (+ day  -1
            (mod
              (- (calendar-day-of-week (list month 1 year)) calendar-week-start-day)
                7))
                  7)))
    (move-to-column
      (+ 
        ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
        (cond
          ;;  1 2 3
          ;;  4 5 6
          ;;  7 8 9
          ;;  10 11 12
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 1)
              (memq month `(1 4 7 10)))
            6)
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 1)
              (memq month `(2 5 8 11)))
            31)
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 1)
              (memq month `(3 6 9 12)))
            56)
          ;;  2 3 4
          ;;  5 6 7
          ;;  8 9 10
          ;;  11 12 1
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 2)
              (memq month `(2 5 8 11)))
            6)
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 2)
              (memq month `(3 6 9 12)))
            31)
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 2)
              (memq month `(4 7 10 1)))
            56)
          ;;  3 4 5
          ;;  6 7 8
          ;;  9 10 11
          ;;  12 1 2
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 3)
              (memq month `(3 6 9 12)))
            6)
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 3)
              (memq month `(4 7 10 1)))
            31)
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 3)
              (memq month `(5 8 11 2)))
            56)
          ;;  4 5 6
          ;;  7 8 9
          ;;  10 11 12
          ;;  1 2 3
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 4)
              (memq month `(4 7 10 1)))
            6)
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 4)
              (memq month `(5 8 11 2)))
            31)
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 4)
              (memq month `(6 9 12 3)))
            56)
          ;;  5 6 7
          ;;  8 9 10
          ;;  11 12 1
          ;;  2 3 4
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 5)
              (memq month `(5 8 11 2)))
            6)
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 5)
              (memq month `(6 9 12 3)))
            31)
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 5)
              (memq month `(7 10 1 4)))
            56)
          ;;  6 7 8
          ;;  9 10 11
          ;;  12 1 2
          ;;  3 4 5
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 6)
              (memq month `(6 9 12 3)))
            6)
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 6)
              (memq month `(7 10 1 4)))
            31)
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 6)
              (memq month `(8 11 2 5)))
            56)
          ;;  7 8 9
          ;;  10 11 12
          ;;  1 2 3
          ;;  4 5 6
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 7)
              (memq month `(7 10 1 4)))
            6)
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 7)
              (memq month `(8 11 2 5)))
            31)
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 7)
              (memq month `(9 12 3 6)))
            56)
          ;;  8 9 10
          ;;  11 12 1
          ;;  2 3 4
          ;;  5 6 7
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 8)
              (memq month `(8 11 2 5)))
            6)
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 8)
              (memq month `(9 12 3 6)))
            31)
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 8)
              (memq month `(10 1 4 7)))
            56)
          ;;  9 10 11
          ;;  12 1 2
          ;;  3 4 5
          ;;  6 7 8
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 9)
              (memq month `(9 12 3 6)))
            6)
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 9)
              (memq month `(10 1 4 7)))
            31)
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 9)
              (memq month `(11 2 5 8)))
            56)
          ;;  10 11 12
          ;;  1 2 3
          ;;  4 5 6
          ;;  7 8 9
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 10)
              (memq month `(10 1 4 7)))
            6)
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 10)
              (memq month `(11 2 5 8)))
            31)
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 10)
              (memq month `(12 3 6 9)))
            56)
          ;;  11 12 1
          ;;  2 3 4
          ;;  5 6 7
          ;;  8 9 10
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 11)
              (memq month `(11 2 5 8)))
            6)
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 11)
              (memq month `(12 3 6 9)))
            31)
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 11)
              (memq month `(1 4 7 10)))
            56)
          ;;  12 1 2
          ;;  3 4 5
          ;;  6 7 8
          ;;  9 10 11
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 12)
              (memq month `(12 3 6 9)))
            6)
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 12)
              (memq month `(1 4 7 10)))
            31)
          ((and
              (eq displayed-month 12)
              (memq month `(2 5 8 11)))
            56) )
        ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
          (* 3 (mod
            (- (calendar-day-of-week date) calendar-week-start-day)
              7))))))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I must be missing something because it looks like the formulas are as simple as (pseudocode):

```
first  = 9 * ( rows - 1 ) 
second = 6 + 25 * ( cols - 1 )
```

based on your edit, you can calculate the rows and cols to move with:

```
if target > display
   difference = target - display
else 
   difference = 12 + target - display
 rows = difference / 3 
 cols = difference % 3
 rowmove = 9 * rows 
 colmove = 6 + 25 * cols
```

And then use the formula above.

My attempt at elisp:

```
(let difference (if (>= target-month display-month) 
                      (- target-month display-month) 
                    (- (+ target-month 12) display-month)))
(let rows (/ difference 3))
(let cols (% difference 3))
(let rowmove (* 9 rows))   
(let colmove (+ 6 (* 25 cols)))
```

Comment: Thank you for taking a stab at the potential solution, which looks like it may work -- i.e., the mathematics checked out.  I will spend some time thinking about how to incorporate that into the function to know for sure if it resolves the issue, and I'll report back.  I turned your mathematics into an `elisp` format:   row 1 = 0 = `(* 9 (- 1 1 ))`; row 2 = 9 = `(* 9 (- 2 1 ))`; row 3 = 18 = `(* 9 (- 3 1 ))`; row 4 = 27 = `(* 9 (- 4 1 ))`; column 1 = 6 = `(+ 6 (* 25 (- 1 1 )))`; column 2 = 31 = `(+ 6 (* 25 (- 2 1 )))`; column 3 = 56 = `(+ 6 (* 25 (- 3 1 )))`

Comment: Would it be possible for you to please expand the formula to take into consideration both `displayed-month` and the target `month`?  I've updated the question to include a few examples:  If `displayed-month` is January (i.e., 1) and the target `month` is August (i.e., 8), then the row equals 18 and column equals 31.  If `displayed-month` is February (i.e., 2) and the target `month` is August (i.e., 8), then the row equals 18 and column equals 6.  If `displayed-month` is March (i.e., 3) and the target `month` is August (i.e., 8), then row equals 9 and column equals 56. . . .

Comment: Thank you for the updated answer -- I'll give it a whirl later on this afternoon / evening, and I'll report back.

Comment: Here is a partial list of the message output for the variables `colmove` and `rowmove` when generating the 12-month calendar and marking a few of the holidays / birthdays / appointments using the full working example of `lawlist-cal.el` for the `displayed-month` of January 2014:  rowmove:  -9 | colmove:  81; rowmove:  0 | colmove:  -19; rowmove:  9 | colmove:  -19; rowmove:  0 | colmove:  6; rowmove:  -9 | colmove:  31; rowmove:  9 | colmove:  31; rowmove:  -9 | colmove:  56; rowmove:  0 | colmove:  56; rowmove:  9 | colmove:  56.  You appear to be very close, but not quite there yet . . .

Comment: If I have some time today, I'll download your github and give it a try.

Comment: Thank you for continuing to work on a solution.  Here is an example why your latest draft doesn't work.  Let's suppose that `displayed-month` = 1 and `target-month` = 1.  The mathematics are as follows:  `difference` = (- (+ 1 12) 1) = 12; `cols` = (/ 12 3) = 4; `rows` = (% 12 3) = 0; `colmove` = (+ 6 (* 25 (- 4 1))) = **81**; `rowmove` = (* 9 (- 0 1)) = **-9**

Comment: Fixed: the comparison should have been >=, and you no longer need the -1s.

Comment: `displayed`:  1 | `target`:  1 | `rowmove`:  0 | `colmove`:  6; `displayed`:  1 | `target`:  2 | `rowmove`:  9 | `colmove`:  6; `displayed`:  1 | `target`:  3 | `rowmove`:  18 | `colmove`:  6; `displayed`:  1 | `target`:  5 | `rowmove`:  9 | `colmove`:  31; `displayed`:  1 | `target`:  7 | `rowmove`:  0 | `colmove`:  56; `displayed`:  1 | `target`:  9 | `rowmove`:  18 | `colmove`:  56; `displayed`:  1 | `target`:  10 | `rowmove`:  0 | `colmove`:  **81**; `displayed`:  1 | `target`:  11 | `rowmove`:  9 | `colmove`:  **81**; `displayed`:  1 | `target`:  12 | `rowmove`:  18 | `colmove`:  **81**

Comment: *Should Be*: `D-M`: 1 | `T-M`: 1 | `rowmove`: 0 | `colmove`: 6; `D-M`: 1 | `T-M`: 2 | `rowmove`: 0 | `colmove`: 31; `D-M`: 1 | `T-M`: 3 | `rowmove`: 0 | `colmove`: 56; `D-M`: 1 | `T-M`: 5 | `rowmove`: 9 | `colmove`: 31; `D-M`: 1 | `T-M`: 7 | `rowmove`: 18 | `colmove`: 6; `D-M`: 1 | `T-M`: 9 | `rowmove`: 18 | `colmove`: 56; `D-M`: 1 | `T-M`: 10 | `rowmove`: 27 | `colmove`: 6; `D-M`: 1 | `T-M`: 11 | `rowmove`: 27 | `colmove`: 31; `D-M`: 1 | `T-M`: 12 | `rowmove`: 27 | `colmove`: 56

Comment: Swapping `rows` and `cols` should do it.  Editing.

Comment: Yes, that last revision looks very very promising :) . . .  the initial tests on all 12 months checked out okay -- I'll run some additional tests and report back.

Comment: AWESOME!!!  Thank you very much.  I'll miss my long-hand solution, which has now been replaced by concise algorithms.  :)